# Installing cot-reports module for anaconda

Tags: python, github, anaconda

I have a problem with installing cot-reports module for Anaconda from the following page:
https://github.com/NDelventhal/cot-reports
I am trying the following command for installation from Anaconda terminal:
conda install git+https://github.com/NDelventhal/cot-reports

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- //github.com/ndelventhal/cot-reports

Any idea on how can I install this modeule for Anaconda?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
pip install cot_reports
```

or

```
pip install git+https://github.com/NDelventhal/cot_reports
```

Answer (score 0):

I just released the package on PyPI three days ago, so it was only available through Github up to this week. It's a PyPI-only package, and is not listed among the Conda-Forge packages so far, so as of now it can only be found on PyPI. However, as for Conda-Forge it does not require the maintainer of the code to do the packaging, this can change any time.

Nevertheless, to install a pip package in a Conda environment, you should be able to just call: pip install cot_reports.